# Pass String from Broadcastreceiver to MainActivity and get it into a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-broadcast

I have to pass a String from Broadcastreceiver to MainActivity. Then I would get this string in a Fragment , how I can do this?

**MyReceiver.java**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bus bus = new Bus();    
        bus.post(new InformationEvent("your string"));        
    }   

}
```

**ScarsdaleHome.java** (Fragment)

```
@Subscribe public void answerAvailable(InformationEvent event) {
            String yourString= event.getInf();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), yourString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scarsdale_home_activity, container, false);

            bus = new Bus();
            bus.register(this);
        return rootView;
    }
```

**InformationEvent.java**

```
public class InformationEvent {
    private String inf;
    public InformationEvent(String inf) {
        this.inf = inf;
    }
    public String getInf() {
        return inf;
    }
}
```

I tryed everything but nothing worked :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easyiest way is to do it with Otto Library from Square.
http://square.github.io/otto/

Create your custom class

```
public class InformationEvent {
    private String inf;
    public InformationEvent(String inf) {
        this.inf = inf;
    }
    public String getInf() {
        return inf;
    }
}
```

Create a singleton for BUS

```
public final class BusProvider {
    private static final Bus BUS = new Bus();

    public static Bus getInstance() {
        return BUS;
    }

    private BusProvider() {
    }
}
```

Publish your event in `BroadcastReceiver`

```
BusProvider.getInstance().post(new InfromationEvent("your string"));
```

Subscribe to this event in your `Fragment`

```
@Subscribe public void answerAvailable(InformationEvent event) {
    String yourString = event.getInf();
}
```

Dont forget to register

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);

    }
```

And unregister BUS in your fragment

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
}
```

Comment: ok , I use your code and I put a Toast in answerAvailable but when the broadcastreceiver is called I can't see the Toast notification..

Comment: @Slaiv206 make sure you use the same `Bus` instance in your `Activity` and `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @EgorN: I've post the code, I don't understand what you mean, please can you explain better?

Comment: @Slaiv206 See, right now you're using two different instances (you're creating `Bus` two times). You should use one common instance. You can find an example [here](http://www.savinoordine.com/otto-an-event-bus-in-android/).

Comment: @Slaiv206 I updated my answer with more clarification

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, given your description one option is: 
Declare the Broadcast receiver inside the Activity, and store the value in a string variable also inside the Activity.
Then, you can pass the value from the activity to the constructor to the fragment, through the fragment's constructor.
I would place the broadcast receiver inside the fragment.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing hard on this. Simple way to describe.

For eg: you are passing data to broadcast from A means,

In A:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("alarmTitle", "Alarm at this time!");
 startActivity(intent);
```

In Alarm Receiver:

```
// i skipped some lines and mentioned important stuffs alone..
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationFragment.class);
  i.putExtra("PASSDATA","getData");
    i.putExtra(Constants.DATAS,
            intent.getExtras().getString("alarmTitle"));// this is you are  getting from previous activity
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
 }
```

In NotificationFragment :

```
   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey(Constants.DATAS)&& bundle.containsKey("PASSDATA")) {
        String eventStrName = bundle.getString(Constants.DATAS); //
     String broadCastData=bundle.getString("PASSDATA");// 
        //now you got the datas from broadcast receiver
}
```

Hope I covered all scenarios.